# Solve $(\frac{dy}{dx}-1)e^{\frac{dy}{dx}}=y$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

> Solve $$\left(\frac{dy}{dx}-1\right)e^{\frac{dy}{dx}}=y$$

I just found a particular solution $y'=\ln x$ hence $y=x(\ln x-1)$ from 'observing'. And check it by differentiating it. But I don't know how to make a strict proof. Any hints would be helpful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take the derivative of the equation to get, outside the constant solution $y=-1$,
$$
y''y'e^{y'}=y'\implies y''e^{y'}=1\implies e^{y'}=x+C, ~~ y'=\ln(x+C)
$$
Now insert into the original equation to get
$$
y(x)=(\ln(x+C)-1)(x+C)
$$

Answer (score 0):

Hint: This equation is a separable one,we get $$\frac{dy(x)}{dx}=W\left(\frac{y(x)}{e}\right)+1$$ and $$\frac{\frac{dy(x)}{dx}}{W\left(\frac{y(x)}{e}\right)+1}=1$$